# How to separate acronyms from the glossary (to put each in different place)?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I got a request to put the list of acronyms at the start of my thesis, rather than at the end where the glossary is located. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

I have tried to separate the acronyms into a separate `acronym.tex` file

```
\newacronym{MCDA}{MCDA}{\gls{multipleCriteriaDecisionAnalysis}}
\newacronym{a}{n}{other example}
```

while the glossary entries are in another `glossary.tex` file

```
\longnewglossaryentry{multipleCriteriaDecisionAnalysis}{
    name={multiple criteria decision analysis (\textmd{also referred to as} multiple criteria decision-making)},%
    text=multiple criteria decision analysis,
    {%
    used to describe any structured approach to determine overall preferences among alternative options, where the options accomplish several objectives; it is often used in government, as in this manual, to describe those methods which do not rely predominantly on monetary valuations

    decision-making analysis that evaluates multiple (conflicting) criteria as part of the decision-making process
}

\longnewglossaryentry{another}{
    name={another},
    {%
    this means something

    or not
}
```

as I just demonstrated.

Then I'd call them in `main.tex` like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

% glossary
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries} 
\input{glossary}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\input{title section}
\input{acronym.tex}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
Text.
\section{Conclusion}
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

which doesn't work - presumably because both acronyms and glossary items fall in the `glossaries` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This template will help you get started.

Compile as `pdflatex` + `pdflatex` + `makeglossaries` + `pdflatex`

Load the entries using `\loadglsentries{<filename>}`

In this example     `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Acronyms}]` will print the (used) acronyms list in the section **Introduccion**, while     `\printglossary[type=main, title={Glossary}]` will add the glossary (used) list to the the section **Conclusion**.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myglossary.tex}
\longnewglossaryentry{multipleCriteriaDecisionAnalysis}{
    name={multiple criteria decision analysis (\textmd{also referred to as} multiple criteria decision-making)},%
    text={multiple criteria decision analysis},
    description= {%
        used to describe any structured approach to determine overall preferences among alternative options, where the options accomplish several objectives; it is often used in government, as in this manual, to describe those methods which do not rely predominantly on monetary valuations
        
        decision-making analysis that evaluates multiple (conflicting) criteria as part of the decision-making process}
}

\longnewglossaryentry{another}{
    name={another},
    description={%
        this means something
        
        or not}
}

\newacronym{MCDA}{MCDA}{\gls{multipleCriteriaDecisionAnalysis}}
\newacronym{O}{OTHER}{other example}
    
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,xindy]{glossaries} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{myglossary} % load entries <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \clearpage  
    
    \section{Introduction}
     See \gls{multipleCriteriaDecisionAnalysis} and \gls{another} 
    
    Also \gls{MCDA} and \gls{O}

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Acronyms}]
    
    \section{Conclusion}
    
    Some text.
    
    \printglossary[type=main, title={Glossary}]%
\end{document}
```